# Handle chunked response as and when received in android

Tags: java, android, mobile, response

I need to handle chunked json response in android, as and when received. Back-end .net web API will be generating chunked json content and pushing it to client using PushStreamContent (as shown [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi)). Android client need to update received content to UI as and when received.
So far I have failed to find any proper way to do this.

Any web content which I can refer to will also do the job.

Comment: This is bit old question but might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055199/have-any-android-developers-had-success-receiving-chunked-transfer-protocol-from

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try that, but the answer seems to rely on 'large enough buffer' to work. Will it be correct way to achieve this? What if chunk size exceeds that of buffer?